# Max value of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Why isn't this working? Is there something wrong with my syntax or anything? I want to echo the max value of the **$row2['startShift']** array but it displays nothing.

```
$query2 = "SELECT startShift,endShift from seats where seatid=".$row['seatid'];
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $startShift = $row2['startShift'];
    echo max($startShift);
}
```

Comment: you want to count all value?

Comment: No i just want to display the maximum value so I used max() but it doesn't echo anything. Any ideas why and how?

Comment: becuse its inside the loop, and you could just get it from the db rather thing get all rows for this one value

Comment: `$row` is a single row, so `$row['startShift']` is not an array. Why not stick `max` in the query?

Comment: `$startShift` is going to be a scalar/single value. It's **NOT** an array.

Comment: I know but what if I want to display every max value should I still not put it inside the loop?

Comment: Why not have MySQL handle your data for you, rather than pulling back results you don't want?  SELECT MAX(startShift) FROM seats WHERE seitid = @seat_id" ?

Comment: But what if for example, seatid=11 has two startShifts it will not be an array?

Comment: If you only want the maximum of `startShift`, why are you also querying for `endShift`?

Comment: No, this is just a part of the code I will also get the maximmum value of the endShift. So to make the code short and readable here I just used startShift for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate a maximum by keeping a separate variable outside of the loop:

```
$maxStartShift = -INF;
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    if ($row2['startShift'] > $maxStartShift) {
        $maxStartShift = $row2['startShift'];
    }
    echo $maxStartShift; // maximum until now
}
```

The `max()` function returns the maximum value of it's arguments, so `max(1, 2) == 2` or `max([1, 2]) == 2`. In your case:

```
echo max($row2['startShift']);
```

Will just return `$row2['startShift']` because that's the maximum of all arguments passed to the function.

Comment: Im sorry im just a beginner in PHP but can i ask one stupid question? What is $maxStartShift = -INF? and what it's for?

Comment: INF is a php constant representing "infinity". If you don't give `$maxStartShift` a very low initial value, the greater-than comparison might not work.

Comment: I have one more favor to ask. If want the minimum value now, how should I go on about this?

Comment: @rez You do the same thing but in reverse; you start with a value of `INF` and then compare if anything is lower than the current minimum.